An adventure movie similar to Romancing the Stone (1984)
I'm looking for a movie which the beginning part of the Colombia scenes are very similar to Robert Zemeckis's Romancing the Stone (1984). The movie's production year is much later than that about between late 90's and 2005.
The movie starts with a middle aged woman about 35, half-drunk and sitting in front of the burning fireplace on her own house. After a while she started to move around and read something. She was blonde, single and about 1.70 - 5' 7'' height. She was probably american. Suddenly she found something and decided to fly to South America. 
I couldn't remember which country she went but it wasn't Argentina or Brazil. It was a country which have tropical monsoon climate like Colombia. When she landed, she got on a bus. After couple of hours the bus stopped. It could be an either crash or engine failure, I couldn't remember. She went outside and started to walk with her luggage on her own. Suddenly a man came out from nowhere and offered to help her. 
He was white, had black hair and eyebrows, had a light beard, about 40 aged and probably american. They started to move on and tried to find a village or a vehicle. Shortly a heavy rain started out and a very similar scene like Michael Douglas and Kathleen Turner in the mud at Romancing the Stone had happened. She lost her luggage and got dirty. Her clothes and body got scratched and torned up while moving deep in the jungle. The heavy rain never stopped during their way. 
It was getting dark and finally they found a leftovers of a small plane and they got into to spend the night. They found a drink, some drugs, bunch of comic books, some canned food, blankets and a flare while searching inside. Probably it was a plane of drug smugglers. They started a fire, ate canned food, took some of the drugs, drank the drink and told each other their youthful memories that the first times they used drugs. Just before she passed out she said '... and now , I'm going to kiss you Mr. ......' and fall asleep. He laughed and covered her up with some blankets and also fall asleep. 
At the morning they reached a small village. The local people looked at them and surprised about their nationality, wounded bodies, dirty and torn clothes. They started to follow pulled out their guns. She stopped suddenly, looked them and said 'Stop! We can come to a conclusion'. 
After this scene there was a commercial break and i couldn't watch the rest. 

That is the EXACT plot of romancing the stone. Right down to the drug smuggling plane.

@Darren I was going to comment the exact same thing, but the OP seems to be convinced it isn't it.

@Darren No i'm pretty sure it wasn't Romancing the Stone . There wasn't any scenes about Turner's sister and the scenes with her publisher . The leading actress was kinda like Turner but she was more beautiful and the leading actor definetely wasn't look like Douglas . He was brunette and more like hispanic with the visage .

The "and now , I'm going to kiss you Mr" is very similar to a bit of dialog in the first Mummy film. @Darren, actually, in Romancing the Stone, a "bad man" makes his appearance first, before the Michael Douglas character. But I agree overall it sounds very similar to the opening of Romancing the Stone.

@Faheem Mitha Yes, i remember that scene from Mummy and it was vere similar that the one i've mentioned. The girl has passed out just like Weisz. Again i've to say that, i'm %100 sure it wasn't Romancing the Stone.

"Coronado" (2003)?  Sounds similar but different details.
http://entervideo.net/watch/f7b892ec540a8d1  (at 0:07:50)

@pori No, it was different from the movie that i've been looking for. There wasn't any war scenes. The lead actress had a curly blonde hair and looked like kind of Erika Christensen with more oval face type and much thinner than her. The lead actor was Hispanic-American that i've mentioned before. The first scene was what i said before and i remember that clearly.

Is it King Solomon's Mine 1985?

Fortune hunter Allan Quatermain teams up with a resourceful woman to help her find her missing father lost in the wilds of 1900s Africa while being pursued by hostile tribes and a rival German explorer.





Can you post info on why you think this is the same movie? Perhaps provide a link to a description of the movie, and quote a portion of it here?

@user1118321 It has a snippet and the trailer, and a link to the IMDB, it has met all the requirements of a concise answer. What exactly are you missing here that you can't find among the information provided?

Yes, now it does. It was originally just the first line of text. Looks good now!

@taylor I watched the trailer and the full movie afterwards  but it doesn't ring any bells. The picture quality was much better and i'm sure it was made in either late 90's or early 00's. The movie took place in South America not Africa. Also there wasn't any war or tribal scenes. However  Sharon Stone is kind of look like the woman that i've mentioned. Thanks for the answer but it's not correct.
